# Java - while loop continues even when it should be done

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a controller which checks the input to get the right name from a "students" list, and somehow, even if I gave the right name, the loop continues.
I'm sure I missing something very obvious.

Here is the code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String str = sc.nextLine();

while (!students.contains(str)){
  System.out.println("Try again");
  str = sc.nextLine();
}
```

edit:
the problem is with the class in the "student" list here's how the class and the list looks like:

```
// this gets filled right from a txt
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

public class Student{
    private String name;
    private int gradeCount;
    private int average;
    private boolean homeWork;
    ...
}
```

and I would like to check the name data member in this class

Comment: What does your `students` list look like?

Comment: Oh damn.. it's a List<Student> so that might be a problem... :D sorry

Comment: What does your `Student` object look like?

Comment: Can you post some more code? Maybe an example?

Comment: Yes, if `students` is a `List<Student>`, then it's NOT going to contain a String.

Comment: Just implement `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Student` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't search for a `String` in a list of `Student`. You need to write your own `contains()` method, possibly something like this:

```
public boolean contains(List<Student> list, String s) {
    for(Student student : list) 
        if(student.getName().equals(s)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (!contains(students, sc.nextLine()))
  System.out.println("Try again");
```

This is of course assuming you have a getter for `name`.

Another option is for your `Student` to implement `Comparable` so that you can use various `Collections` methods and you can compare the `Student` objects to each other. An example of that would be:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Student s2) {
        return name.compareTo(s2.getName());
    }
}
```

You can then do the following:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Student("Chris"));
students.add(new Student("John"));
students.add(new Student("Frank"));
students.add(new Student("Devon"));

Student me = new Student("Chris");
students.contains(me); // true
```

Since you have `Comparable` now implemented, you can also sort the `Student` object by `name` by using `Collections.sort(students)`.

More examples on using `Comparable` in Java https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Woah, awesome thanks :D it was realy helpful, i really appreciate it :)

Comment: This is a good approach as long as the `name` attribute/field in a `Student` object is a unique identifier. That is, two `Student` objects with the same name refer to the same "person".

Comment: @geri I added another example at the top to shorten your code :) Hope it helps! Make sure to accept the answer too if it is what you needed

Comment: @Khaled yes that is true. However it appears that he is scanning in names (just a guess)  so I am using the assumption that the name field is the one that should be compared. Unique or not

Comment: If the guy is in a beginner Java course, which is almost certain, then there's no way they've covered writing their own compare methods. Based on the code he's working with they're probably checking the understanding of loops and conditionals, not custom compare methods.

Comment: @ChrisSharp I feel like the first example is definitely in that scope. What would you recommend to simplify it?

Comment: I wrote a solution below, that someone downvoted, but does exactly what you need and at a level that your instructor is probably expecting.

Comment: @ChrisSharp That code does the exact same process as mine except it introduces a special case to worry about. I prefer to avoid as many special cases as I can.

Comment: It does not do what your code does. It is a beginner level comparison using loops that a first or second semester student would be expected to write. Your code is clearly a better solution but it's not what any first or second semester instructor expects and either it will cause him to gain grand expectations or make his teacher very suspicious about where the code came from.

Comment: @ChrisSharp this isn't really a discussion for this thread anymore. If you would like to continue this discussion we can move to the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136586/discussion-between-chris-and-chris-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

User a primer read:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sandbox {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     Boolean found = false;
     String input;

     ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
     students.add(new Student("Jim"));
     students.add(new Student("Kim"));
     students.add(new Student("Bill"));
     students.add(new Student("Betty"));

     System.out.println("Enter the name of a student to check");
     input = keyboard.nextLine();
     if(students.get(0).getName().equals(input)) {
         System.out.println("You found " + students.get(0).getName());
         found = true;
         keyboard.close();
     }
     while(!found) {
         System.out.println("Try again");
         input = keyboard.nextLine();
         for(int i = 1; i < students.size(); i++) {
            if(students.get(i).getName().equals(input)) {
                System.out.println("You found " + students.get(i).getName());
                found = true;
                keyboard.close();
                break;
            }
         } 
     }   
 }
```

Student class

```
public class Student {
    String name;

    public Student () {

    }

    public Student (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? It does exactly what he said he wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a getter for the Student object, you can map the list of `Student` objects to a list of students names (String) and then perform the `.contains()` call on that list. So try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.nextLine();

// Create a List<String> of student names
List<String> names = students
                       .stream()
                       .map(student -> student.getName())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

while (!names.getName().contains(str)){
  System.out.println("Try again");
  str = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String str=null;
boolean isFound=false;
while (!isFound)
{
 str = sc.nextLine();
    for(Student stdObj:students)
     if(stdobj.name.equals(str))
      {
        isFound=true;
            break;
      }
   if(!isFound)
    System.out.println("Try again");
}